# Laravel package bmatovu/laravel-xml. How to remove/change <document> in xml response

Tags: php, xml, laravel, api, package

I am creating a simple API which has to return XML responses, i installed bmatovu/laravel-xml package. The problem is i am required to response with root tags as `<api/><api>`, but it's set automatically to `<document></document>`. Any ideas how can i change this?

**My code:**

```
    $time = time();
    $data = [
        'api' => [
            'method' => 'call',
            'success' => '1',
            'time' => $time,
        ]
    ];
    return response()->xml($data);
```

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
<api>
    <method>call</method>
    <success>1</success>
    <time>1595760619</time>
</api>
</document>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok found it.

Had to change these parameters in XMLresponse.php file installed with package.

```
    public $options = [
    'root' => 'document',
    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
    'version' => '1.0',
    'slug' => true,
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to edit the vendor files. This should suffice

```
Route::get('/users/{user}', function (Request $request, int $userId) {
    $user = User::findOrFail($userId);

    return response()->xml($user, 200, [], ['root' => 'user']);
});
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<user>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>jdoe</name>
    <email>jdoe@example.com</email>
</user>
```